# `or` of all the value in a column in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe with a `BooleanType` column. I wanted to calculate the `OR` of all the value in that column. How can I do it.

For example if I have dataframe like following:

```
id | aBooleanColumn
1  | true
2  | false
3  | false
```

Then what I want is dataframe.select(or("aBooleanColumn")) should return `OR` of all the value in the column. In the above case it should return a dataframe with one row and one column containing `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// OR - True if at least one record in the column is true ~ c.reduce(_ | _)
def or(c: Column) = (count(when(c, 1)) > 0).alias(s"or($c)")
```

and for good measure

```scala
// AND - True if all records are true ~ c.reduce(__ & __)
def and(c: Column) = (count(when(c, 1)) === count(col("*"))).alias(s"and($c)")
```

Test:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  (1, true, true, false), (2, false, true, false), (3, false, true, false)
).toDF("id", "aBooleanColumn", "truthyBooleanColumn", "falsyBooleanColumn")


df.select(
  or($"aBooleanColumn"), or($"truthyBooleanColumn"), or($"falsyBooleanColumn")
).show
// +------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
// |or(aBooleanColumn)|or(truthyBooleanColumn)|or(falsyBooleanColumn)|
// +------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
// |              true|                   true|                 false|
// +------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+

df.select(
  and($"aBooleanColumn"), and($"truthyBooleanColumn"), and($"falsyBooleanColumn")
).show
// +-------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
// |and(aBooleanColumn)|and(truthyBooleanColumn)|and(falsyBooleanColumn)|
// +-------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
// |              false|                    true|                  false|
// +-------------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

In Python:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, count, when

def or_(c):
    c = c if isinstance(c, Column) else col(c)
    return (count(when(c, 1)) > 0).alias("or({})".format(c))

def and_(c):
    c = c if isinstance(c, Column) else col(c)
    return (count(when(c, 1)) == count(col("*"))).alias("and({})".format(c))
```

Test:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [(1, True, True, False), (2, False, True, False), (3, False, True, False)],
  ("id", "aBooleanColumn", "truthyBooleanColumn", "falsyBooleanColumn")
)

df.select(
    or_("aBooleanColumn"), or_("truthyBooleanColumn"), or_("falsyBooleanColumn")
).show()


# +-----------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
# |or(Column<b'aBooleanColumn'>)|or(Column<b'truthyBooleanColumn'>)|or(Column<b'falsyBooleanColumn'>)|
# +-----------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+
# |                         true|                              true|                            false|
# +-----------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------------------------+

df.select(
    and_("aBooleanColumn"), and_("truthyBooleanColumn"), and_("falsyBooleanColumn")
).show()


# +------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
# |and(Column<b'aBooleanColumn'>)|and(Column<b'truthyBooleanColumn'>)|and(Column<b'falsyBooleanColumn'>)|
# +------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
# |                         false|                               true|                             false|
# +------------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to a Dataset and use `reduce`

```
val result: Boolean = df.select("aBooleanColumn").as[Boolean].reduce(_ || _)
// result: Boolean = true
```